# Compiling with external library (OASIS, OCamlfind)

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind, oasis

I have a new project I'm trying to compile with OASIS. All my packages but one are installed with opam.

My `_oasis` file looks like this :

```
(* usual package fields *)

Executable myexe
  Path:       src
  BuildTools: ocamlbuild
  MainIs:     myexe.ml
  BuildDepends:
        some_packages_installed_with_opam
        mylocalpackage
```

I tried `oasis setup` then `./configure` but OCamlfind answered that it couldn't find `mylocalpackage`. So I decided to take a look at where OCamlfind looks for packages and found out that you can set an `OCAMLPATH` variable to add directories where packages might be installed. So I did `export OCAMLPATH=path_to_mylocalpackage:$OCAMLPATH` and tried again.

`oasis setup` gives me this result :

```
findlib: [WARNING] While parsing 'path_to_my_local_package/META.in': 
         The `directory' directive is required in this META definition
```

and `ocamlfind query mylocalpackage` gives me this result :

```
ocamlfind: Package `mylocalpackage' not found
```

I don't know if I should write in `_oasis` where to find this package or if changing the `OCAMLPATH` variable is the solution. But if it is, I don't understand the warning.

---

### Steps to reproduce

For those who would like to try it :

- Download [why3](https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/37313/why3-0.88.3.tar.gz)
- ```
  ./configure --enable-local
  make
  ```
- Create a new project with this `_oasis` file

  ```
  OASISFormat: 0.4
  Name:        myexe
  Version:     0.1
  Synopsis:    test file
  Authors:     SO
  License:     CC-BY-NC-SA
  Plugins:     StdFiles (0.4), DevFiles (0.4)
  Alphafeatures:          ocamlbuild_more_args
  XOCamlbuildExtraArgs:
    -use-ocamlfind

  Executable myexe
    Path:       src
    BuildTools: ocamlbuild
    MainIs:     myexe.ml
    BuildDepends:
          unix,
          str,
          num,
          dynlink,
          zip,
          menhirLib,
          why3
    NativeOpt:            -dtypes -g -annot
    ByteOpt:              -dtypes -g -annot
    CompiledObject:       best
  ```
- ```
  oasis setup
  ./configure
  ```
- You should have this error : `ocamlfind: Package 'why3' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a pretty non-standard approach that you're trying. Not sure, why you need it, as usually it is better just to install the package. Anyway, when you're using the `OCAMLPATH` variable you need to pass it a path to the lib folder, that contains folders that, respectively, contains the `META` files. I'm having the following repository structure:

```
.
├── proj
└── why3-0.88.3
```

and in the `proj` folder, I'm running the `configure` script with the following OCAMLPATH:

```
OCAMLPATH=../why3-0.88.3/lib/:$OCAMLPATH ./configure
```

After that everything works, and you don't even need to pass the `OCAMLPATH` variable anymore to the compilation, linking, or execution stages.